# Am i mining any ethereum or is it just very slow

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

Hello i am brand new to this, actually days new and see alot of activity on my cmd prompt but when i have checked my address that i have entered it doesnt seem to be acquiring any ether. I let my computer run over night last night and still nothing has shown up. at first i just let the ethminer run with my address and now i have hopefully successfully started mining in he nanopool and am unsure if i have changed any result. please help. here is was started with to start the miner and what i see continuously in the prompt.

My initial to start mining

[image]

What i see once the miner is running
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks fairly standard.  It shows you are receiving work and performing hashes.

You need to have a share accepted for nanopool to update.  Maybe double check the address is correct. If that's correct, it could be you that you just haven't had a share accepted yet.

Comment: ok, by share accepted do you mean whoever runs the pool accepting the amount of work i have accomplished and then i should receive payment for it? sorry brand new to this lol

Comment: Yes, when you mine a valid share, nanopool will accept it and credit your account accordingly.

Comment: awesome, and i ll be able to see that pop up on my mist wallet or just check on etherchain.org?

Comment: Nanopool has a minimum payout of 0.2 ETH. This means you must mine 0.2 ETH before nanopool will credit your eth address

Comment: alright i guess i ll just let it run and see how it goes after sometime mining. Thanks for the help bud!